# Which techniques for creating an .exe from a .jar file allow the .exe to easily operate on a file?

Tags: java, windows, exe

[Several options for creating a .exe program from a executable .jar program exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file). I would like to be able use the Windows "open with..." right-click menu to open a file with that program (or, alternatively, by dragging the file onto the program).  Currently, I am unable to use the .jar program to open a file in this manner.  Instead, I am forced to click the "File:Open" menu within the .jar program.  I'm hoping that by wrapping the .jar with a .exe, opening files in this way will become possible.

Presumably, this requires the .jar program to be written to accept files passed to it in this manner.  I know very little about Java, nor about the detail of this particular program, so I do not know if this is impossible, trivial, or dependent on how the .jar program is written.

Comment: *"I'm hoping that by wrapping the .jar with a .exe, opening files in this way will become possible."*  
No such Voodoo.  OTOH  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  ..and it supports registering an interest in file associations, either in the launch file, or programmatically using the JNLP API.  Here is a small [demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result without .exe. Create a .bat file that runs your java command, eg:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar C:\myprog.jar com.mycompany.MainClass %1
```

The %1 will pass first argument which is the file you "right click -> open with"

Comment: Could you please explain the com.mycompany.MainClass part? (It doesn't seem to work. "The system cannot find the path specified.")

Comment: com.mycompany.MainClass is basically the name of the java class that has `main()` method (eg: your entry point class). You need to replace it with whatever your main class is. You don't need to specify this if you jar already contain entry point configuration on the manifest file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html. The script above also assume you have an environment variable %JAVA_HOME% setup to your jvm installation

Comment: Yep, it turns out I don't have %JAVA_HOME%, but now I've replaced this with the path to java.exe .  It now runs the .jar command, but it seems to ignore the file passed to it.  Is this a possible symptom of not configuring the entry point class correctly, or does the fact that the .jar command executed mean this is not a problem?

Comment: In order for the argument to take effect the Java code need to actually to consume it. You need to open the source code (or speak to the programmer) and check whether this is the case. In java command line arguments are passed through `main(String[] args)` argument. `args[0]` reference the first command line arg

Comment: I used http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui to decompile the .jar file.  I found `main(String[] args)`, but it looks like the Java code does not actually use `args[0]`.   And I think it would be quite challenging to fix this.  Bummer.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: If anyone wants a go at it, I was trying to fix PDF Scissors.  http://www.pdfscissors.com/pdfscissors.jar

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be able to right click on something and "run a jar on it" you could either setup the file associations to call "c:\full\path\to\java.exe -jar c:\full\path\to\your\file.jar %1" and then accept the filename as the first argument to main, or you could (as you noted).

If you convert your jar to an exe, then you'd just need to associate it like ".exe %1"

https://github.com/rdp/redcar/blob/master/lib/redcar/installer.rb#L22 is kind of how I did it once, though it's not exactly what you'll need, it's kind of an example.